# Exchange vars between API and software's core

Tags: java, plugins, add-on

I am developping a screenshot software which can load plugins from JAR. Thoses are developped using the API package, which is made of interfaces to implement, so the person who wants to make a plugin does not have to use the full source code.

This works well for adding like action (Upload to X or X host for example), but what if I want to send variable the other way around, like from a plugin TO the core ? How am I supposed to do this?

The only solution I can think of would be to use callbacks, but I don't find this so clean...

By the way, is my solution to use interface that devs implements, which I then  instanciate is correct ? Or there is a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is the most common way to implement such a scenario. You give plugins an instance of a class (instantiated by core) and they can store it for future use (e.g. to pass data to the core or trigger another action). Normally name of such classes ends with Context (e.g. BundleContext, PluginContext, etc.).

Another pattern is to use a sort of Mediator class. A class with some static methods that plugins can use to send some data to core or trigger some actions. I don't like it and it's not a very clean solution, but it makes it much easier for plugin developers to access the API as they don't need to store the context instance and respect its life cycle. This pattern is used widely in IntelliJ IDEA architecture.

As you're developing a plugin based system, I highly recommend you to take a look at OSGi architecture and APIs. It can be helpful in this regard.